# Application kernel debugging

Tags: c, debugging, windows-7, kernel

I have done some hacking in windows `interrupt table` and trying to test it through an application. I don't want to put a `break point` in the kernel functions which gonna get invoked.(I have modified some of the first level interrupt handlers.) I want to start from the application and then wanna go to the actual hacked part of the code by `single stepping`. I wanna know if `Windbg` is good enough to do that? Can I put a `breakpoint` in my application and then go onto debug `windows`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use remote debugging (e.g, from a second computer) to single-step through the kernel. It is impossible to use breakpoints or single-stepping on the kernel of the local machine, as the debugger and other applications rely on the kernel to work.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/151981

Comment: yes, i gonna use remote debugging. But can i start debugging from application and then go into kernel?

Comment: You don't need two physical pcs, something like virtual pc should work just fine. @agent.smith: you need to make sure you are running in ring0, so your probably gonna need to start from kernel mode, and follow the launch of the app from there

Comment: @Necrolis: Thanks. Do u know how to launch an application in kernel mode. Is there any way to launch the application from Windbg?